# inserting data into access database using .net core

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I am trying to insert data to Access 365 in .net core API. Below is what I did to insert the data, but I am getting an error saying that :

```
The type or namespace name 'OleDbConnection' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.OleDb' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I added the assembly reference to :

```
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Odbc;
    using System.Data.OleDb
```

Below is my partial C# code:

```
  public void PrimeAccessRules()
        {
            List<RecLoad> recList = new List<RecLoad>();
            recList = getPrimeData();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        @"Data source= C:\Users\test\recload.accdb";

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
        }
```

The error is coming right on this line:

```
System.Data.OleDb.**OleDbConnection**
```

saying that OleDbConnection does not exists

Any help will be highly apprecaited.

Comment: Have you added the [System.Data.OleDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb/4.7.0) package?

Comment: No, I didnt. I just added it and the error is gone. I thought, by adding System.Data.oledb is enough Thanks for the help. error is gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types in the `System.Data.OleDb` namespace are part of the `System.Data` assembly in .NET Framework, but they're not included in .NET Core or .NET Standard.  Since you're targetting one of the latter two (.NET Core), you'll need to add the [System.Data.OleDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb) package to your project.